# updateMany gives Error: collection.updateOne requires update operator

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to update a number of records using updateMany and an aggregation pipeline, but I keep getting this error when I try to run it. I'm confused by the error since it mentions updateOne and that's not what I am using. I want to update a handful of records, set the number of games played, then set the low and high score based off of the current value of the score field.

I have been through the documentation for [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) and as far as I can tell, I have things the way they should be.

`[Error] Error: collection.updateOne requires update operator`

```
db.items.updateMany(
    {'game': 'pacman'},
    [
        {$set: {'games_played': 53}},
        {$set: {
            $min: {'score_low': '$score'},
            $max: {'score_high': '$score'}
        }}  
    ]
)
```

I have also tried the following and get the same error.

```
db.items.updateMany(
    {'game': 'pacman'},
    [
        {$set: {'games_played': 53}},
        {$set: {
            'score_low': {$min: {'score_low': '$score'}},
            'score_high': {$max: {'score_high': '$score'}}
        }}  
    ]
)
```

Edit:

And this gives the same error.

```
db.items.updateMany(
    {'game': 'pacman'},
    [
        {$set: {'games_played': 53}},
        {$set: {
            'score_low': {$min: '$score'},
            'score_high': {$max: '$score'}
        }}  
    ]
)
```

Comment: This is the correct syntax: `'score_low': { $min: '$score' }`

Answer (score 0):

Look like a syntax issue related to [$min](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/min/index.html) and [$max](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/max/index.html). You could try with [update](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with `multi:true` option or [updateMany](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/index.html) as follows:

```
 db.items.updateMany(
        {'game': 'pacman'},
        [
            {$set: {'games_played': 53}},
            {$set: {
                'score_low': {$min: '$score'}},
                'score_high': {$max: '$score'}}
            }}  
        ])

db.items.update(
    {'game': 'pacman'},
    [
        {$set: {'games_played': 53}},
        {$set: {
            'score_low': {$min: '$score'}},
            'score_high': {$max: '$score'}}
        }}  
    ], {multi:true}
)
```